# Need python Regex for handling sub-string

Tags: python, regex

I want to check where the string (Product Name) contains the word beta, Since I am not so good in regex writing :
eg.

```
"Crome beta"
"Crome_beta"
"Crome beta2"
"Crome_betaversion"
"Crome 3beta" 
"CromeBerta2.3"
"Beta Crome 4"
```

So that I can raise error that this is not valid product name , its a product version.
i wrote a regex which is able to cought the above strings

```
parse_beta = re.compile( "(beta)", re.I)
if re.search(parse_data, product_name):
     logging error 'Invalid product name'
```

But if the product name contains the word having substring beta init like *"tibetans product"* so the above regex it is parsing beta and raising error. i want to handle this case.Any one can suggest me some regex.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `"beta in product_name.lower()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should cover all the cases of beta version names, where the regexp should give a match.

So we start writing the pattern with the first example of beta `"Crome beta"`:

```
' [Bb]eta'
```

We use [Bb] to match `B` or `b` in the second place.

The second example `"Crome_beta"` adds `_` as a separator:

```
'[ _][Bb]eta'
```

The third `"Crome beta2"` and the forth `"Crome_betaversion"` examples are covered by the last regexp.

The fifth example `"Crome 3beta"` forces us to change the pattern this way:

```
'[ _]\d*[Bb]eta'
```

where `\d` is a substitute for [0-9] and `*` allows from `0` to `infinity` elements of `\d`.

The sixth example `"CromeBeta2.3"` shows that Beta can have no preceding _ or space, just start with the capital. So we cover it with `|` construction which is the same as `or` operator in Python:

```
'[ _]\d*[Bb]eta|Beta'
```

The seventh example `Beta Crome 4` is matched by the least regexp (since it starts with `Beta`). But it can also be `beta Chrome 4`, so we would change the pattern this way:

```
'[ _]\d*[Bb]eta|Beta|^beta '
```

We don't use `^[Bb]eta` since `Beta` is already covered.

Also, I should mention, we can't use `re.I` since we have to differentiate between `beta` and `Beta` in the regex.

So, the test code is (for Python 2.7):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re, sys

match_tests = [
"Crome beta",
"Chrome Beta",
"Crome_beta",
"Crome beta2",
"Crome_betaversion",
"Crome 3beta" ,
"Crome 3Beta",
"CromeBeta2.3",
"Beta Crome 4",
"beta Chrome ",
"Cromebeta2.3" #no match,
"betamax" #no match,
"Betamax"]

compiled = re.compile(r'[ _]\d*[Bb]eta|Beta|^beta ')
for test in match_tests:
    search_result = compiled.search(test)
    if search_result is not None:
        print("{}: OK".format(test))
    else:
        print("{}: No match".format(test), file=sys.stderr)
```

I don't see any need to use negative lookbehind.
Also, you used a capturing group `(beta)` (parenthesis). There is no need for it either. It would just slow down the regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Try `((?<![a-z])beta|cromebeta)`. (the word beta not preceded by a letter or the full word cromebeta)

I'll add a quote from http://docs.python.org/library/re.html to explain the first part.

> (?<!...) Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded
>   by a match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion.
>   Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must
>   only match strings of some fixed length. Patterns which start with
>   negative lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the
>   string being searched.

Comment: But the data can be a like "CromeBeta2.3" like that.

Comment: @Shashi Then you must learn to make good examples in the question. I'm quite inflexible on this. My answer follows the rules set in the question.

Comment: @Shashi If you think your question was wrongly written, then you can correct it. I'm not so inflexible on changing my reply based on corrected questions :-) [Errare Humanum Est](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errare_humanum_est#errare_humanum_est)

Comment: actually the the example that i have gave ,i missed some combination now i have added, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Shashi I hope the sixth example isn't about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bertha_(howitzer))

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've actually got two concepts in the Product Name string: Product and version, with a separator of whitespace and underscore, from the examples you gave.  Use a regex such that splits the two concepts, and search for the word `beta` only in the version concept.

Comment: No actually the above string is only the product name but some time the product version get inserted in product name string so to check that i need regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[Bb]eta(\d+|$|version)|^[Bb]eta "
```

**test with grep:**

```
kent$  cat a                                            
Crome beta
Crome_beta
Crome beta2
Crome_betaversion
Crome 3beta
CromeBeta2.3
tibetans product
Beta Crome 4


kent$  grep -P "[Bb]eta(\d+|$|version)|^[Bb]eta " a     
Crome beta
Crome_beta
Crome beta2
Crome_betaversion
Crome 3beta
CromeBeta2.3
Beta Crome 4
```